# Error while connecting remote connection SFTP in Netbenas

Tags: java, php, connection, server

While I am trying to connect my project to remote server in `NetBeans.`
Please help me to resolve this **error** in `SFTP connection`.

> Can't connect to `server 31.XXX.XX.XX`
>
> Cause.Session.connect:Java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out

Answer (score 0):

Try to telnet to IP:PORT and check whether it is working.